# Insert an array in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to insert an array into my MySQL database in the format a,b,c.

```
 `var_dump($pvt_contacts)`
```

results

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "102" [1]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

I tried

```
`implode(',',$pvt_contacts)'
```

but it echos Array not 102,3 as I expected . Please help me

Comment: I understand what you want, but I must tell you it is a very terrible way to do it. What exactly do you want to achieve? There **must** be an other way to do it. Storing an array in mySQL is so wrong.

Comment: You are getting me wrong Oltarus . Actually I have an array $pvt_contacts which I want to insert to database in the format 102,2,4

Comment: Duplicate topic here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql>

Comment: what is exactly your query ? i'm pretty sure i know where is the problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save PHP array to MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want `102,3`, then you're off by one (your pointing to a parent array, and not the elements):

```
implode(',',$pvt_contacts[0]);
```

- If you're trying to store an array in a DB, I recommend [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). (despite its prevalence in Drupal, ExpressionEngine, Wordpress, etc. this is not generally the best idea).
- If you're trying to sent an array to js, I recommend [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json_encode.php).
- If you're doing something else I need more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use multiple rows to store the data, instead of storing the whole array into it. If you insist, here is the way:

Convert your array to the following format:

```
[key1]{value1}#[key2]{value2}#.... etc
```

You can use `explode` to convert it back to array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be either [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) or [var_export()](http://php.net/var_export). But you should only use those if you do not intend to use the data inside the database in any way. If you want to run e.g. SELECT queries on this array data you should store it in a normalized way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use serialize(), unserialize() 
or  json_encode() , json_decode()

That would make it easier for you to write , and retreive back original data without the need of parsing your stored data yourself .
Here are some good links to assist you :

[Preferred method to store PHP arrays (json_encode vs serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 0):

You can `implode` your array into a string then `explode` it back. Default separator is the `,`. If you want to run `SELECT` queries then you can use the MySQL-specific `FIND_IN_SET()` function however this whole scenario is **not recommened**, you should use a normalized way as others suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert array to JSON. It will convert array to string and you will be able to store it.

- [json_encode](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php),
- [json_decode](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php);

Anyway, I don't think that this it the right way how to deal with the problem. Say, for example, you would need to store blog entries and tags for them into database.

How you do it know?

Save blog entry and tag into one table, one row. You convert all entries tags and save all into database.

How you should do it?

Make two tables:

- `entries`,
- `entry_tags`;

All info that's related to entry save into `entries`. For example: `title`, `description`.
All tags save into `entry_tags`. In that table there are `id` (primary key), `entry_id` (ID that have relationships with `entries` ID) and `tag` that simply holds the name.

I hope this will help you!