# Selecting MYSQL data from PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm creating a social network. I want to have a user be able to subscribe to people. In theory, when a user clicks the subscribe button, PHP would add that user's ID to an array in their MYSQL listing under the column "subscribed-to". Now, I want to have a news feed style home page. I want to know, if I pull the "subscribed-to" data via PHP, how could I show only the posts (also in a MYSQL table) of the people the user is subscribed to?

Comment: Can you show us a schema of the relevant tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION to combine all the posts from different tables, then use the "IN" clause to get all the userID's you want to follow based on the current userID:

Example:

```
$userFavs = "SELECT userID FROM favs WHERE followerID = '#loggedinUserID#'"

mysql_query("SELECT 'wall' as type, body, date FROM wall WHERE userID IN ($userFavs) 
UNION
SELECT 'photo' as type, caption, date FROM photos WHERE userID IN ($userFavs) UNION... etc
ORDER BY date DESC");
```

If you run the query thru mysql_fetch_array() it'll return something like this:

```
Array => {
[0] => { type = "wall", body = "This is a wall update", date = "1234567890" },
[1] => { type = "photo", caption = "Us at the beach", date = "..." },
...
}
```

You need to make sure that you have the same amount of columns in each SELECT statement everytime you call "UNION", otherwise it will not work. You can /fake/ columns as I have done with the `type` column above.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that info. I have the basic idea now, but I'm very beginner. All I want for now is text statuses. I'm assumng that all I have to do is use `$userFavs = "SELECT userID FROM favs WHERE followerID = '#loggedinUserID#'"
 
mysql_query("SELECT 'wall' as type, body, date FROM wall WHERE userID IN ($userFavs)  
ORDER BY date DESC"); `

Comment: Yep. That will work. Make sure you use the correct indexes and caching though, otherwise that will probably be a very slow query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your array in the DB. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql) might help as well!