# Dynamic fields name - how it should be done?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jquery

See the image below, I want to add many product as I want by clicking on "Add More Product" and then 2 new elements will be appear (Category and Items dropdowns). This will be done via jQuery to copy previous `<li>` and insert a new one.

When the elements are created, what the name of the dynamic fields should be? The data will be added into $_POST and I can insert into database.

[image]

HTML below, see dynamic fields name (example: `name="items_2"`, `name="items_2"`):
I have also added hidden input of `current_added_products` field. This tell me how many products currently added. Not sure if I need this?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Category</label>
        <select name="category_1"> 
            <option>CPU</option>
            <option>HDD</option>
        </select>
        <select name="items_1"> 
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Category</label>
        <select name="category_2"> 
            <option>CPU</option>
            <option>HDD</option>
        </select>
        <select name="items_2"> 
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="current_added_products" value="2" />
        <input type="button" class="add_more_product" value ="Add More Product" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, before the elements are created how to get the next numbers to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.add_more_product').click(function() {
    var $ul = $('ul:last');
    $ul.clone().find('select').attr('name', function(i, cur) {
        return cur.match(/\D+/g).join('') + (Number(cur.match(/\d+/g).join('')) + 1)
    }).end().insertAfter($ul)
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7zwn/

---

```
$('.add_more_product').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $ul = $('ul:last');
    $ul.clone().insertAfter($ul)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7Zeb/

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the elements naming is fine? What do you think about using array? example: `name="category[]"`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back You are welcome, that's a good option and is easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You could give them all a `name` of `category[]` and `items[]`, then when they are posted you'll end up with a numerically indexed array, this way you don't need to worry about appending a number to each newly created element. For example selecting `CPU` with `Item 1` and `HDD` with `Item 2` would result in the following once posted:-

```
array
  'category' => 
    array
      0 => string 'CPU' (length=3)
      1 => string 'HDD' (length=3)
  'items' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Item 1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Item 2' (length=6)
```

This will make it a lot easier to add new form elements:-

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Category</label>
        <select name="category[]">
            <option>CPU</option>
            <option>HDD</option>
        </select>
        <select name="items[]">
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" class="add_more_product" value ="Add More Product" />
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add_more_product').on('click', function() {
        $('li:last').clone().appendTo('ul');
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyYkN/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `name="item[1]"`, `name="item[2]"`. This will result in an array in your `$_POST['item']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your html you got from copy using following code

```
htmlCopy.replace(/category_[0-9]+/, function(a){
       return "category_"+ (current_added_products+1);
});
htmlCopy.replace(/items_[0-9]+/, function(a){
       return "items_"+ (current_added_products+1);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use aray `name` as described in above answer. more to add in the databases use code like,

```
if (!$con){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$authors = $_POST['Author'];
foreach($authors as $author) :
$sql="INSERT INTO savetest (type, number) VALUES ('{$_POST['type']}','{$author}')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
endforeach;
```

more [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10235971/1564818) post can help you..