# Is it possible to dump an array into a mysql text field and read it back as an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I would like to log every submission of a web form made on our website from the $_POST array, and save it to our mysql database.

I'm outputting the following to the submission page which is obviously very readable:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print "</pre>";
```

Looks like:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => value1
    [field2] => value2
    [field3] => value3
)
```

Is it possible to save it exactly like that but to a text field?

And then what about pulling that information back out of the table and converting it back to an array for processing?

Comment: have you considered `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` ?

Comment: No, a `print_r()` is not easily converted to the original array. Instead you should `serialize` or `json_encode` your data.

Comment: YES! see `serialize()` and `unserialise()` or I prefer `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`

Comment: yes you can use json_enocde and at display time you can use json_decode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql

Comment: use json_encode($_POST,true); and store in text field and after fetching the field use json_decode($variable,true); decode into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_encode($_POST,true);` and store in text field and after fetching the field use `json_decode($variable,true);` decode into array.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks all! Knew there must be a simple way...