# How to Store Array in Mysql Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to store array in mysql database. with key and value

Following are code i used

```
         $name= "prashant";
         $lname= "kumbhar";
         $test = "testing";

        $array = array('fname'=>$name,'lname'=>$lname,'test' =>$testing);
```

Store these $array in database using php

Comment: you need to use json to store array data in mysql

Comment: please.. can you tell me how to do this

Comment: You should have a look at [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)

Comment: Funny, if I Google that title of yours I see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql). Please tell me, how were you unable to find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to store data in mysql table.

```
<?php
$name= "prashant";
$lname= "kumbhar";
$test = "testing";

$array = array('fname'=>$name,
               'lname'=>$lname,
               'test' => $test
         );

$res = json_encode($array);
echo "Convert from array to json :" .$res;

echo "\n\nFrom json to array:\n";
print_r(json_decode($res));
```

**output**

```
Convert from array to json :
{"fname":"prashant","lname":"kumbhar","test":"testing"}

From json to array:
stdClass Object
(
    [fname] => prashant
    [lname] => kumbhar
    [test] => testing
)
```

At the time of retrieve data in array form then use `json_decode()`

**Working Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/678634)**

Comment: can i store directly  $result = json_encode($array); like this

Comment: you need to store $result data/output in database

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize the array and store the string in the database:

```
serialize ($array);
```

If you want to use it just unserialize the result that you've get from the database

```
$array = unserialize ($databaseResult);
```

If you prefer json you can do the same with `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Comment: when i use serialize array then data goes 0 and user unserialize then data  store a:15:{s:18:"electricity_backup";s:18:"electricity backup";s:15:"air_conditioned";s:15:"air conditioned";s:22:"djcredit_card_accepted";}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you can save that serialized string to the database

Answer (score 0):

use convert array into json format using json_encode and then store in database, you can convert json string format back to array using json_decode.  Example

```
  $name= "prashant";
  $lname= "kumbhar";
  $test = "testing";

  $array = array('fname'=>$name,'lname'=>$lname,'test' = $testing);
  $data_for_db = json_endcode($array);
```

You can convert stored json format data back to normal array as below

```
$array = json_decode($data_for_db);
```

Thanks