# How to change value of special key in json using php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm inserting value with implode and get this type json

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "f_name":"Mitrajit",
      "l_name":"Samanta",
      "class":"XII",
      "section":"A,B,C",
      "roll":"1",
      "status":"1"
   }
]
```

but I want this type :-

```
[
  {
    "f_name" : "Mitrajit",
    "l_name" : "Samanta",
    "class"  : "XII",
    "section": ["A","B","C"],
    "roll"   : "1",
    "status" : "1"
  }
]
```

how can I get `"A,B,C"` to `["A","B","C"]`?

Comment: can you clear specifically what is your main problem? you can just push A, B, C to section element of the array. Can you post your array from which you want to make this array of object?

Comment: yes if I insert a,b,c as array in mysql database with php so who can I show data like ["a","b","c"] after json_encode()

Comment: then try [serialize] to store in mysql http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php and [unserialize] to show data http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: this could give you more idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql

Comment: I edit my question please check twice

Comment: `A,B,C` is string type but `["A","B","C"]` is array

Comment: @Mohammad so I just ask how to show and insert as array in json

Comment: You create first json or want to convert the first to second json?

Comment: @Mohammad yes I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json_decode()` to converting json to php array. Then select `section` value in json array and use `explode()` to converting it to array. At the end convert php array to json using `json_encode()`

```
$json = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
$json[0]["section"] = explode(",", $json[0]["section"]);
$jsonStr = json_encode($json);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/8MaIF)